# Good rigorous textbook on cybernetics?

Tags: reference-request, control-theory

I am looking to read a good rigorous book about cybernetics. I've read some things but they seemed somewhat basic. Are there any good rigorous textbooks on it?

**EDIT**: basically, I am interested in understanding things like "the good regulator theorem", and things like it (hopefully there are more results in roughly that direction?); also interested in the relation between this and information theory. I am not so interested in "let's apply this to understand the real world of robotics/biology/etc", though its fine if references are made to this as long as the rest of the text is mathematically rigorous.

Comment: The term "cybernetics" is a bit like "mechatronics"... everybody seems to mean some different combination of the more classical fields with it. Can you be more specific of what you want to learn about? Saying what you don't mean may also help.

Comment: @steveheim. Thanks for the clarification. Does my edit clarify enough? Please tell me if I should give more information.

Comment: I think so, but I won't be able to help you. I'm more resourceful on that side that you're not interested in : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer:* I don't consider myself to be any expert in cybernetics and most of the links and articles mentioned below have been taken from a Google search.

---

[This link](http://pespmc1.vub.ac.be/CSBOOKS.html) gives a list of references used for the course "Introduction to Systems Science" at SUNY Binghamton.

[Here](http://www.cybsoc.org/books.htm) is a sample of books recommended by members of the cybernetics society as useful introduction to the science of Cybernetics. Quite a comprehensive list of books are mentioned.

[This is quite an old article](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00335636509382744?journalCode=rqjs20) introducing cybernetics and information theory. See also [here](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01969727408621678?journalCode=ucbs19).

A recent article (compared with the two mentioned above) would be found [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020025510003658). Also, a very good exposition can be found [here](https://www.princeton.edu/~hos/Mahoney/articles/cybinfo/cybinfo.html).

---

Hope these resources help you.

Answer (score 0):

Of course W. Ross Ashy - Introduction to Cybernetic, he formulated the law of requisite variaty. There are exercises and solutions. This is a superb book, very clearly explained. After you worked your way through it, you can move on to other topics of cybernetics.